# Linq to populate values of a class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

I have a class

```
public class Row : IExtensible
{
    public Row();

    [ProtoMember(1, IsRequired = true, Name = "key", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public byte[] key { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, Name = "values", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public List<Cell> values { get; }
}
```

I can populate manually using the following approach:

Edit :
//column and data are sample byte[] values

```
CellSet.Row row = new CellSet.Row { key = sampleKey };
Cell value = new Cell { column = column1, data = data1 };
row.values.Add(value);
```

I need to populate these values in LINQ,this is what I have been trying:

```
var result =
(
    from a in firstrow
    let valuesset = a.Split(',')
    from l in valuesset
    select new CellSet.Row
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //values = new List<Cell>() //Not possible since only get is there
    }
).ToList();
```

How to add values to the object CellSet.Row?

I have also tried this

```
//Edit:
//Read the xml file row by row and process it

var result =
(
    from a in firstrow
    let valuesset = a.Split(',')
    from l in valuesset
    select new CellSet.Row
    {
        key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        //values = new List<Cell>() //Not possible since only get is there
    }.values.Add(value12)
).ToList();
```

Getting an error in values like :

> An expression of type 'string[]' is  not allowed in a subsequent from clause with IEnumerable<>

Comment: Where do you get the column1 and data1 ? How we can extract them from `valuesset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
Func<byte[], IEnumerable<Cell>, Row> create =
    (k, cs) =>
    {
        CellSet.Row row = new CellSet.Row { key = k };
        row.values.AddRange(cs);
        return row;
    };

var result =
(
    from a in firstrow
    let valuesset = a.Split(',')
    from l in valuesset
    select create(
        Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
        new [] { value12 })
).ToList();
```

Now, since your code wasn't clear as to how it should exactly work the answer isn't quite there either. But this should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Just one more clarification : when I use select create(byte1[], new[] { new Cell { column = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(column1), data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(l[0].ToString()) },                                              I am getting an exception "l[0] cant be evaluated " in run time and "Out of bounds exception after execution .                     Is it not possible to access "l" values inside select create(//here)?

Comment: @user1907849 - It's really not clear what your types are, but `l` appears to be a `string`, so `l[0]` is a `char`. Is that what you're expecting?